# How do I place text in the exact center of the textview?

Tags: android, layout, native, center

I'm developing an native android App, And I faced an issue that text in TextView is not placed in the center_vertical.
Text is already placed in the center_horizental. The problem is vertical ...

Of course, the text tends to be centered vertically. However, it is located slightly below the exact center.

This is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/calendarLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="74dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black_7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        tools:text="30"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black_1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCheckIn"
        tools:text="8:30"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/erp_rounded_primary_bg"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCheckout"
        tools:text="18:30"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/erp_rounded_black4_bg"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAttendGrp"
        tools:text="출장"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black_1"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem code is this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCheckIn"
    tools:text="8:30"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/erp_rounded_primary_bg"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCheckout"
    tools:text="18:30"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/erp_rounded_black4_bg"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I tried using gravity, layout_gravity, and layout_centerInParent to fix it but didn't work.

What shold I add to place text in the center_vertical?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertical alignment of the text is independent of the specific text. But "ÂÂÂ", "AAA", "aaa", "yyy" all have a different vertical "center", so the text may appear slightly off-center in a specific case. If you know that the text is a time, you can correct the deviation from the vertical center manually with e.g.

```
android:paddingBottom="0.8sp"
```